# Selenium - complete ajax loading autoscroll to bottom of page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a webpage where when you scroll to the bottom it then loads more results via ajax.  You can do several iterations of this before it completes.  Bit like what facebook does.

I am trying to write a selenium script to keep going to the end of the page until it completes.

Something like this sort of half completes it.. I just don't know how to determine if page is at the bottom - so i can put it inside a loop of some sort?

**My Attempt**

```
    By selBy = By.tagName("body");

    driver.findElement(selBy).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
    System.out.println("Sleeping... wleepy");

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(selBy).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);

    System.out.println("Sleeping... wleepy1");
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    //etc...
```

**Could Look like this?**
hasScroll() isnt a real method.  I put that there to demonstrate what im trying to achieve

```
   while (driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).hasScroll()) {
        driver.findElement(selBy).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
        System.out.println("Sleeping... wleepy");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
//Get total height
By selBy = By.tagName("body"); 
int initialHeight = driver.findElement(selBy).getSize().getHeight();
int currentHeight = 0;

while(initialHeight != currentHeight){
        initialHeight = driver.findElement(selBy).getSize().getHeight();

        //Scroll to bottom
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scroll(0," + initialHeight + ");");

        System.out.println("Sleeping... wleepy");
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        currentHeight = driver.findElement(selBy).getSize().getHeight();
}
```

Hope help!