# How to scrape products from finite-scrolling page using scrapy?

Tags: api, selenium, scroll, scrapy, infinite-scroll

I recently started to learn scrapy and decided to scrape [this site](https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/zhenshchiny-novinki-l1180.html?v1=2111785).

There are 24 products on 1 page, and when you scroll down more products load.

There should be about 334 products on this page.

I used scrapy and tried to scrape the products and information inside, but I can't make scrapy to scrape more than 24 products.

I think, I need selenium or splash to render/scroll down to the end, and then I would be able to scrape it.

This is the code that scrapes 24 products:

```py
import scrapy

custom_settings = { 
   'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/92.0.0.0'
    }

class BookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'basics2'
    api_url = 'https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/zhenshchiny-novinki-l1180.html?v1=2111785&page'
    start_urls = ['https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/zhenshchiny-novinki-l1180.html?v1=2111785&page=1']


#Def parse goes to the href of every product 

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath("//div[@class='product-grid-product-info__main-info']//a"):
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_book)
        for link in response.xpath("//ul[@class='carousel__items']//li[@class='product-grid-product _product product-grid-product--ZOOM1-columns product-grid-product--0th-column']//a"):
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_book)    
        for link in response.xpath("//ul[@class='carousel__items']//li[@class='product-grid-product _product product-grid-product--ZOOM1-columns product-grid-product--1th-column']//a"):
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_book)   
        for link in response.xpath("//ul[@class='carousel__items']//li[@class='product-grid-product _product product-grid-product--ZOOM1-columns product-grid-product--th-column']//a"):
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_book)   
        for link in response.xpath("//ul[@class='carousel__items']//li[@class='product-grid-product _product carousel__item product-grid-product--ZOOM1-columns product-grid-product--0th-column']//a"):
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_book) 
        for link in response.xpath("//ul[@class='product-grid-product-info__main-info']//a"):
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_book) 


#def parse-book gets all the information inside each product
    def parse_book(self, response):
        yield{
            'title' : response.xpath("//div[@class='product-detail-info__header']/h1/text()").get(),
            'normal_price' : response.xpath("//div[@class='money-amount price-formatted__price-amount']//span//text()").get(),
            'discounted_price'  : response.xpath("(//span[@class='price__amount price__amount--on-sale price-current--with-background']//div[@class='money-amount price-formatted__price-amount']//span)[1]").get(),
            'Reference' : response.xpath("//div[@class='product-detail-color-selector product-detail-info__color-selector']//p[@class='product-detail-selected-color product-detail-color-selector__selected-color-name']//text()").get(),
            'Description'  : response.xpath("//div[@class='expandable-text__inner-content']//p//text()").get(),
            'Image' : response.xpath("//picture[@class='media-image']//source//@srcset").extract(),
            'item_url' : response.url,
            # 'User-Agent': response.request.headers['User-Agent']
    }
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO, you might find this question and answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850974/selenium-scroll-to-end-of-page-in-dynamically-loading-webpage the question is in JavaScript but the first answer is for Python. Once you have all the products loaded then you should be able to work-out how to scrape all the products. If it unloads products from the top of the screen as you scroll down, then you can scrape items each time your scroll function is called, and keep a record of the ids of the already scraped products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use so slow and complex selenium, You can grab all the requred data from `API` like:

```
import scrapy
import json
 
API_URL = "https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true"

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = [API_URL]
        
    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
 
    def parse(self, response):
        json_response = json.loads(response.text)
        datas = json_response["productGroups"][0]['elements']
        for data in datas:
            yield {
                "name":data.get("commercialComponents")[0]['name']
                
                }
```

**Output:**

```
{'name': 'БОТИЛЬОНЫ ИЗ ТКАНИ С ОТДЕЛКОЙ ПАЙЕТКАМИ'}
2022-11-19 22:39:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'name': 'ТУФЛИ С ОТДЕЛКОЙ ПАЙЕТКАМИ, НА КАБЛУКЕ'}
2022-11-19 22:39:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'name': 'ФУТБОЛКА С ВОРОТНИКОМ-СТОЙКОЙ'}
2022-11-19 22:39:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'name': 'СУМКА-ШОПЕР С УЗЛАМИ НА ЛЯМКАХ'}
2022-11-19 22:39:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'name': 'МИНИ-СУМКА ГЕОМЕТРИЧЕСКОЙ ФОРМЫ'}
2022-11-19 22:39:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'name': 'МИНИ-СУМКА ГЕОМЕТРИЧЕСКОЙ ФОРМЫ'}
2022-11-19 22:39:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'name': 'БЕСШОВНАЯ ЮБКА ИЗ МЯГКОЙ ТКАНИ'}
2022-11-19 22:39:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'name': 'ТОП ИЗ ЭЛАСТИЧНОГО ТРИКОТАЖА'}
2022-11-19 22:39:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'name': 'БЕСШОВНОЕ ПЛАТЬЕ ИЗ МЯГКОЙ ТКАНИ'}
2022-11-19 22:39:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'name': 'ТОП ИЗ ЭЛАСТИЧНОГО ТРИКОТАЖА'}
2022-11-19 22:39:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'name': 'ТОП ИЗ ЭЛАСТИЧНОГО ТРИКОТАЖА'}
2022-11-19 22:39:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'name': 'БЕСШОВНЫЕ ЛЕГИНСЫ ИЗ МЯГКОЙ ТКАНИ'}
2022-11-19 22:39:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-11-19 22:39:52 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 330,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 186484,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 3.171018,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 19, 16, 39, 52, 441260),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 2096267,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'item_scraped_count': 476,
```

**Update:** See the updated answer how to extract image url from the `API`  responsed data of this website.

```
import scrapy
import json
 
API_URL = "https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true"

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = [API_URL]
        
    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
 
    def parse(self, response):
        json_response = json.loads(response.text)
        datas = json_response["productGroups"][0]['elements']
        for data in datas:
            name = data.get("commercialComponents")[0]['xmedia'][0]['name']
            #print(name)
            path = data.get("commercialComponents")[0]['xmedia'][0]['path']
            #print(path)
            ts = data.get("commercialComponents")[0]['xmedia'][0]['timestamp']
            #print(ts)
            img = 'https://static.zara.net/photos//' + path+ '/'+name+'.jpg?ts=' +ts
            #print(img)

            yield {
                "image_url": img
                
                }
```

**Output:**

```
{'image_url': 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2022/I/0/1/p/1067/785/800/2/1067785800_2_2_1.jpg?ts=1668003224849'} 
2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'image_url': 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2022/I/0/1/p/1067/785/800/2/1067785800_1_1_1.jpg?ts=1668003224932'} 
2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'image_url': 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2022/I/0/1/p/1067/744/505/2/1067744505_1_1_1.jpg?ts=1668155524538'} 
2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'image_url': 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2022/I/0/1/p/8586/866/099/2/8586866099_15_1_1.jpg?ts=1668085284347'}2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'image_url': 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2022/I/0/1/p/8587/866/099/2/8587866099_1_1_1.jpg?ts=1668003219701'} 
2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'image_url': 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2022/I/0/1/p/8586/866/099/2/8586866099_15_10_1.jpg?ts=1668081955599'}
2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'image_url': 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2022/I/0/1/p/5388/629/711/2/5388629711_1_1_1.jpg?ts=1668008862794'} 
2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'image_url': 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2022/I/1/1/p/6672/010/800/2/6672010800_1_1_1.jpg?ts=1668172065554'} 
2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'image_url': 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2022/I/1/1/p/6672/010/002/2/6672010002_2_3_1.jpg?ts=1668164312812'} 
2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'image_url': 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2023/V/0/1/p/5584/151/800/2/5584151800_2_8_1.jpg?ts=1668696590284'} 
2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'image_url': 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2022/I/0/1/p/7901/938/822/2/7901938822_2_5_1.jpg?ts=1668767172364'} 
2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'image_url': 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2022/I/0/1/p/7901/935/822/2/7901935822_2_5_1.jpg?ts=1668764555064'} 
2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'image_url': 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2023/V/0/1/p/5584/151/800/2/5584151800_2_1_1.jpg?ts=1668691124206'} 
2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.zara.com/ru/ru/category/2111785/products?ajax=true>
{'image_url': 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2022/I/0/1/p/7901/936/822/2/7901936822_2_5_1.jpg?ts=1668767061454'} 
2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-11-20 23:16:14 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 330,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 186815,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.670308,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 20, 17, 16, 14, 180866),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 2100146,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'item_scraped_count': 474,
```

... so on

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried using Api method, i put the get method in Insomnia but couldnt make the code to work to actually read the commercial components. Using API method can I get url of pictures? I am asking because I only saw paths, not URLs

Comment: Well deserved acceptance! I will make sure to upvote it once I have enough reputation as well. Do you know whether I can scrape information inside each of the product( there are more images and information inside each of the link). Is it even possible using API method?

Comment: Actually, You will be able to scrape your required data from api yourself after acquring a bit more  experience. That's why learn more  how to extract data such way from  api from online and sure you will get success.Thanks